# bootstrap + кирпичная кладка (Salvattore)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Код html:

```
<div class="container list">
    <div class="row masonry" data-columns>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="pr">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img class="ph" src="/photo/${pr.photo.id}"/>
                    <div class="caption">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
```

На странице подключаю:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/salvattore.min.js"></script>
```

Стили медиа:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .masonry[data-columns]::before{
        content: '1 .col-xs-12';
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .masonry[data-columns]::before{
        content: '3 .col-sm-4';
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px)and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .masonry[data-columns]::before{
        content: '4 .col-md-3';
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .masonry[data-columns]::before{
        content: '6 .col-lg-2';
    }
}
```

Проект запускаю в идее на том кате, для сетки использую плагин salvattore.

Желаемое: разрешение от 1200 - 6 колонок, разрешение от 992 - 4 колонки, разрешение от 768 - 3 колонки, разрешение до 767 - 1 колонка.

Реальность: при загрузке страницы на самом высоком разрешении контент выводится в одну колонку, при изменении размера - становится 6 колонок на всех разрешениях, если страницу перезагрузить в браузере на самом высоком разрешении колонки сбрасываются от 6-ти до 1-й, на остальных разрешениях остаётся 6 колонок. Что делаю не так, подскажите плз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас везде стоит `max-width` хотя вы задаёте рамки. Надо поставить `min-width` куда надо:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .masonry[data-columns]::before{
        content: '1 .col-xs-12';
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .masonry[data-columns]::before{
        content: '3 .col-sm-4';
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .masonry[data-columns]::before{
        content: '4 .col-md-3';
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .masonry[data-columns]::before{
        content: '6 .col-lg-2';
    }
}
```